# convert csv scientific notation to number in unix

Tags: csv, unix, awk, sed

I have the following data in a csv file:-

```
year,num_val
2008,4.31333E+16
2009,473538088A5031009
2010,4.31333E+16
```

I want to convert the scientific notation on the above csv file present in unix box and I wanted the result as below :-

```
year,num_val
2008,43133300000000000
2009,473538088A5031009
2010,43133300000000000
```

I tried doing the same using awk but i am getting partial data as below :-

```
awk -F',' '{printf "%16.0f\n",$2}' file.csv
```

Result Received :-

```
43133300000000000
        473538088
43133300000000000
```

Can anyone guide me to a more optimal solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a bit on the safer side, I would do the following in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($2==$2+0){$2=sprintf("%16.0f",$2)}1' file
```

This checks if `$2` is a number and if so, it converts it. Just checking if the line contains a `E` might fail if the string in the second line could print an E.

Even more robust, if you only want to convert the scientific notation, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($2==$2+0)&&($2~/E|e/){$2=sprintf("%16.0f",$2)}1' file
```

Comment: Thank You. This one is also working and here i do not need to specify all column number. With this approach I can target only the column that I need.